# XmlSerializer adding data instead of overwriting

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, stream, xml-serialization, overwrite

I'm busy with a Windows Phone project and I'm using XmlSerializer to add data everytime a button is pressed. Unfortunately, the data in the xml file is overwrited instead of being added. How do I make sure I add the data?

Here's my code:

```
private void ReadXmlFile()
    {
        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Progress.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Progress>));
                    List<Progress> data = (List<Progress>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

                    this.listBox.ItemsSource = data;              
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

List<Progress> data = new List<Progress>();
            data.Add(new Progress() { BMI = bmi, Length = Length, Weight = Weight });

            XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Progress.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Progress>));
                    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);
                    }
                }
            }


            ReadXmlFile();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The XmlSerializer will never modify XML, it just generate a new XML every time you use it.
If you need to modify XML you should use XmlDocument or XDocument instead of the serializer.

The following workflow are required to achieve your goal:

1) Read current file to XDocument
2) Modify the XDocument
3) Save content of the XDocumen

Comment: You mean something like this?
`XDocument xDocument = new XDocument(
new XElement("Progress",
new XElement("BMI", bmi),
new XElement("Weight", Weight),
new XElement("Length", Length)
));
using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isolatesFileStream =
new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Progress.xml", FileMode.Create, isolatedStorageFile)){xDocument.Save(isolatesFileStream);}
}`

Cause this also overwrites

Comment: You can also delete file et recreate.